# Laravel Report Analytics - Slow foreach Query Loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

I am currently building an analytics system for our job site, we have a database of applications which are time-stamped.

I am attempting to get the amount of applications per day with a specific month, I am doing this using ajax and chart js, the code works however, the php is extremely slow and I just wondered if there was anyway to improve this. Below is the code I am using:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$qmonth,$qyear);
  foreach (range(1, $days) as $key => $number) {
      $count = App\report::whereYear('date_created', $qyear)->whereMonth('date_created', $qmonth)->whereDay('date_created', $number)->count();
      $cart[] = array('day' => $number, 'count' => $count);
  }
  $result = json_encode($cart);
  print_r($count);
```

I pass two url parameters to the php code $qmonth and $qyear, I am running a query between 28 and 31 times depending on how many days are in the month,  since I need to count the amount of applications on a daily basis. Is there any that I can do this without querying 30 times in a loop, since I assume this is why the query is so slow?

Best regards,
Gareth
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: 30 queries for a single request is definitely a lot. What you could do is **1)** write a complex SQL query which returns you the desired result already calculated and grouped by MySQL or **2)** get all the results from `App\report` with a single query and transform them with PHP to fit what chartjs exoects.

Comment: How would I go about doing the second option?

Comment: why don't you get the result via MYSQL and then iterate over the result on db? it's much faster when you work on the lower layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work using this code

```
 $cart = [];
  $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $qmonth, $qyear);
  $reports = App\report::whereYear('date_created', $qyear)->whereMonth('date_created', $qmonth)->select('date_created')->get();
  if ($reports->count()) {
  }else{
    $items = array();
  }

  foreach($reports as $i){
      $items[] = $i['date_created']->format('j');
  }


  $countarray = array_count_values($items);

  foreach (range(1, $days) as $day) {
      $count = isset($countarray[$day]) ? $countarray[$day]  : 0;
      $cart[] = ['day' => $day, 'count' => $count];
  }

  $result = json_encode($cart);
   print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would go to do a PHP transformation of all the results:

```
$cart = [];
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $qmonth, $qyear);
$reports = App\report::whereYear('date_created', $qyear)->whereMonth('date_created', $qmonth)->get();
$reports = $reports->groupBy(function ($report) {
    return date('d', $report->date_created);
})->toArray();

foreach (range(1, $days) as $day) {
    $count = isset($reports[$day]) ? count($reports[$day]) : 0;
    $cart[] = ['day' => $day, 'count' => $count];
}

$result = json_encode($cart);
print_r($count);
```

Note that when using `groupBy` on the `$reports` collection you have to return the day of the report. I'm not sure what format you're using, but if it's timestamp you could format it with the `date` function to return the day, as shown in the exmple.

Let me know how fast this runs.

**EDIT:**

If *date_created* is a carbon instance, return `$report->date_created->format('d');` from the reports collection `groupBy` method.

Comment: Getting this error date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, object given

Comment: @GarethJones in the `groupBy` method replace the `date('d', $report->date_created)` call with `return $report->date_created->format('d');`. This is because most likely your *date_created* property is carbon instance.

Comment: the count returns zero for some reason here is an output [{"day":1,"count":0},{"day":2,"count":0},{"day":3,"count":0},{"day":4,"count":0},{"day":5,"count":0},{"day":6,"count":0},{"day":7,"count":0},{"day":8,"count":0},{"day":9,"count":0},{"day":10,"count":0},{"day":11,"count":0},{"day":12,"count":0},{"day":13,"count":0},{"day":14,"count":0},{"day":15,"count":0},{"day":16,"count":0},{"day":17,"count":0},{"day":18,"count":0},{"day":19,"count":0},{"day":20,"count":0},{"day":21,"count":0},{"day":22,"count":0},{"day":23,"count":0},{"day":24,"count":0}...

Comment: When returning $reports after formatting date_created $report->date_created->format('d'); It appears that the date isnt being formatted correct since in the array it is still in the following format - 2017-07-01 07:40:46

Comment: @GarethJones this is just to group your reports by day, its not to format your date for output. Try to var_dump `$reports` and see if you have some results, the keys of they array are for which day this report is.

Comment: I understand that however, during this loop 

foreach (range(1, $days) as $day) {
          $count = isset($reports[$day]) ? count($reports[$day]) : 0;
          $cart[] = ['day' => $day, 'count' => $count];
      }

we are trying to count how many applications on which day, else return zero which is why all of the days return a count of zero, so how can I get it so that the out put lists the count for those specific days